# Plotting prediction from averaged GLM model: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found

Tags: r, glm, predict

I have produced an averaged GLM model (to find the habitat preference of a species), and I want to graph the shape of the relationship for each of the most important variables, “x1” and “x3” (understorey cover and canopy cover), against my response variable, “species” (species presence). I have been using the “predict”(predict.averaging) function, but I keep running into the same error:

`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found`

More details and code:

My dataset, “data.csv”, is a table with 13 rows. The first 12 rows are scaled habitat variables (10 continuous, 2 categorical), named x1-x12. Row 13 is the response variable – species presence/absence (1 or 0).
Here is my code:

`library(MuMIn)`

`dataset <- read.csv(file = 'data.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

`options(na.action = "na.fail")`

`m1 <- glm(species ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + x12, data=Dataset, family=binomial())`

`ms1 <- dredge(m1)` #Running different model combinations

`d2subset <- get.models(ms1, subset = delta < 2)` #Models with delta AIC <2 are selected.

`avgm <- model.avg(d2subset)` #DeltaAIC<2 models are averaged.

`summary(avgm)` #Shows 'x1' to be the most significant variable.

The following code, attempting to predict from the averaged model, causes an error:

`predict(avgm, data.frame(dataset$x1), se.fit = TRUE, type = "link", backtransform = TRUE, full = TRUE)`

Errors produced:

`Error in predict.averaging(avgm, dataset$x1), se.fit = TRUE,  :`

`'predict' for models '2211', '163', '147', '179', '2227', '183', '131', '2195', '167', '2275', '227', '243', '211', '148', '1171', '435', '151', '3235', '247', '2215', '155', '2231', '659', '2291', '2219' and '171' caused errors.`

`In addition: There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`

`Warning messages:`
`1: In eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found`

`2-13: In eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found`

`14: In eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x5' not found`

`15-26: In eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found`

I have looked into this a lot, but I still don't understand where the error comes from or how to work around it. I would be very grateful for any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Does you model `avgm` only include the variable `x1`?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl No, it includes variables x1 through to x12

Comment: Well, there is your answer.

Comment: Hi @Roland, do you mean that I should make a new model with only the variable 'x1' and predict from that?

Comment: I'm not telling you what to do, @J.C.Wahl basically told you what causes the error. Personally, I think you are missing a model validation step and I don't understand why you even do model development if you don't have the necessary prediction data.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment. Thank you for the advice. Do you see a particular error here to make you suggest that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the model includes covariates `x1`-`x12` you need to include all variables for `predict`, not just `x1`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can produce a graph using: plot(predict(avgm, dataset, backtransform = TRUE)) , but I am not sure how this shows the relationship between x1 and the response variable in particular. Sorry if I am misunderstanding something

Comment: Could you try adding `predict(avgm, type = "terms", terms = "x1")`? Also, I would try to read the documentation for `predict.averaging` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf)

Comment: That code works, and graphed into a different scatter plot than before, so I think I am getting closer now. I did read the predict.averaging documentation, but didn't fully understand it (I am fairly new to R), so I will read it again now that I have a better understanding and try to figure out exactly what has been produced by the code. Thanks very much for your help :)